# Appropriate way to manage different views for portrait and landscape?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, orientation, xib

I'm developing an app targeting `iOS 7` and above. I'm using `storyboard` and `autolayout`, and I have to show different layouts of each storyboard scene depending on the device orientation, I mean, for example: in portrait I may have a button at a certain place that has to be shown in another place in landscape, or I may have controls in portrait that should disappear in landscape and have to rearrange the rest of controls.

My question is: when there are a lot of differences between portrait and landscape, should it be better to manage all this changes by programmatically updating constraints, or should it be better to create different `nib` files and load the corresponding according to the orientation?

Comment: As long as you are having the same set of UI elements in both orientation you can play with size classes to have two different sets of layout constraints. Check this out [http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial)

Comment: @Gandalf Thanks. Since I have to support iOS 7, I was told to better avoid using size classes...

Answer (score 0):

use size classes their will be no problem in giving support to ios7 . I have tested their were no major problems in ios7 while using size classes.

Comment: It seems that it has some restrictions in iOS7 (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/DeployingSizeClassesonEarlieriOSVersions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH13-SW1), so I decided to avoid using it just in case...